# Cannot connect to my own Wifi Ubuntu 18.04 HP ZBook 15

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, ubuntu-18.04

So as the title says I cannot connect to the router at home, though I can use other networks such as eduroam.

When I first set up my router I could, but since that first day I get a ”?” in the right corner where the signal strength should be displayed. Since I can use other networks I first thought my router was the problem, but it might as well be my computer. My phone can connect just fine. I had to struggle to get it to be able to connect through Ethernet and I have issues with light and sound as well, so I want to see what I can do with my computer first.

Comment: You don't seem to have a programming-related problem; this isn't a general tech helpdesk.

Comment: I didn’t know this was only for programming

Comment: Please take the [tour] and see [ask].